# unwanted angular value link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

The picture shows an edit page, which use can add commands to the list, delete and so on. The value should be only updated to the actual array when user click update button. Below are some of my code:

```
  $scope.editSchedule = function(index){
              console.log(index);
      $scope.editScheduleValue = {
        name: $scope.currentSchedule[index].name,
        trigger: $scope.currentSchedule[index].trigger,
        repeat: $scope.currentSchedule[index].repeat,
        commandList: $scope.currentSchedule[index].commandList,
        scheduleIndex: index
      };
      var dailog = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'app/partials/edit-schedule.html',
          controller: editScheduleController,
          size: 'lg',
          scope: $scope
      });
    };
```

This is a edit button scope, which will get the actual value from curremtSchedule array.

```
$scope.addCommand = function(){
    console.log("addCommand");
    $scope.addRoom = $scope.equipment[$scope.roomSelected].name;
    $scope.addEquipment = $scope.equipment[$scope.roomSelected].equipment[$scope.equipmentSelected].name;
    $scope.addEquipmentCommand = $scope.equipment[$scope.roomSelected].equipment[$scope.equipmentSelected].command[$scope.commandSelected].type;
    $scope.editScheduleValue.commandList.push({
      room: $scope.addRoom,
      equipment: $scope.addEquipment,
      command: $scope.addEquipmentCommand
    })
  };
```

This is my Add command button code, which push data to editScheduleValue array.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in editScheduleValue.commandList" ui-tree-node>
        <td style="width: 5%"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical" ui-tree-handle></i> </td>
        <td style="width: 5%">{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td style="width: 30%">{{x.room}}</td>
        <td style="width: 30%">{{x.equipment}}</td>
        <td style="width: 30%">{{x.command}}</td>
        <td>
        <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="remove(this)">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
      </tr>
```

The problem that I encouter is whenever I delete, add command not only the editScheduleValue array updated, but the currentSchedule array as well, I really do not understand why is this 2 array is somehow linked. Please help~~~ 
Thank you.

Comment: Where is your update function ?

Comment: Suzo, I haven't write my update function code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace

`commandList: $scope.currentSchedule[index].commandList,`

With

```
commandList: angular.copy($scope.currentSchedule[index].commandList),
```

and this 2 arrays are not link anymore, I do not quite understand why it is, but here the answer for my problem.